# Python sqlite3 error about number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm sure this has been asked, and answered before, but either I'm stupid or then none of the answers work for me. Maybe I just don't understand it. However, here's the problem; I got this class:

```
import sqlite3

class User:
   def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age



   def saveToDatabase(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
        cur = connection.cursor()

        cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users")
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE users (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, age INTEGER)")
        cur.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users VALUES (?,?)", (self.name, self.age))

        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

    @staticmethod
    def printUserFromDatabase(name):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
        cur = connection.cursor()

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=?", name)
        print(cur.fetchone())

        connection.close()
```

And it works, database gets created, and I can add users to it, but when ever I try to print an user from database, this happens:

```
>>> tom = User("Tom", 24)
>>> tom.saveToDatabase()
>>> User.printUserFromDatabase("Tom")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    User.printUserFromDatabase("Tom")
  File "C:\Users\Markus\Desktop\foo\foo.py", line 25, in printUserFromDatabase
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=?", name)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since name is iterable it tries to unpack it ... put it in a tuple with just itself to fix

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=?", (name,))
```

Comment: works, but I ran into a new problem. Whenever I insert new user to the database, others get deleted, what causes this? I think it's cause of my table creation, but how should I create the table then?

Comment: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, age INTEGER)"

Comment: Ahh, easy as that... Thanks :)

Comment: use that instead of CREATE TABLE. .. so you dont just recreate an empty table each time